# Why does my book say that "to wear a nice dress" is an error in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, exam-questions

> Ritika decided to get up early (1)/ to wear a nice dress (2)/ and visit her aunt. (3)/ No Error (4).

What is the error in above sentence? My book says (2) is wrong, but I didn't understand.

Comment: Could you rephrase the question? It's not clear.

Comment: Does the answer key contain an explanation or a proposed correction?  Do the instructions mention the kinds of error that are relevant to the exercise?    At a glance I'd guess that the answer key is simply wrong, but I don't have the complete context of the original exercise question so I can't be sure.

Comment: Possibly they want you to use a different verb, not "**to wear**".

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything grammatically wrong with the sentence. But there is a logic problem. When the word "to" is used in a construction like this, it means "for the purpose of" or "making possible". So the sentence is saying that Ritika got up early so that she would be able to wear a nice dress, or that she got up early because she wanted to wear a nice dress. It is difficult to see how getting up early is necessary to be able to wear a nice dress.

A better sentence would be, "Ritika decided to get up early and wear a nice dress to visit her aunt."

Comment: Also, in this case *to* is short for *in order to*, which corresponds to *for the purpose of*.

Comment: @Clare Yes, that's basically what I was trying to say.